# Alterar cor do texto em uma ListView (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Olá, pessoal estou com um probleminha um tanto que chato. Estou tentando mudar a cor de um Texto dentro de uma Listview padrão do android, porém, ele não altera. Já tentei mudar a cor no Layout, mudei por código e nada. Vejam meus códigos de tentativas:

**Modificação via código:**

```
  @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_avisos, container, false);

            TxtSemAviso = view.findViewById(R.id.TxtSemAviso);

            final ArrayList<String> avisos = preencherDados();

            final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                    (DashBoardActivity.context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, avisos){
                @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
                @Override
                public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    // Como o simple_list_item_1 retorna um TextView, esse cast pode ser feito sem problemas
                    ((TextView) view).setTextColor(R.color.colorverde2);
                    return view;
                }
            };
```

**Modificação via XML:**

```
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
        android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/colorverde2"/>
```

Comment: Você quer alterar a cor de apenas um item da listview ou de todos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz o seguinte. Cria em res/layout um Xml com nome de: `simple_list`

cole:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
        android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/colorverde2"/>
```

No seu `adapter` ao invés de chamar:

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

chame:

```
R.layout.simple_list
```

Comment: Isso funciona também! Obrigado pela ajuda. Eu consegui o resultado que queria mudando meu                    
 ((TextView) view).setTextColor(R.color.colorverde2);
para  ((TextView) view).setTextColor(COLOR.GREEN);